# My Screen Flickers when I run a 3D game

Tags: windows-8, graphics-card

First of all, Here are my computer specs.

- Intel Core 2 Duo processer @ 2.6 GHz with 64-bit architecture.
- DDR 3 1 GB RAM
- Windows 8 32-bit OS
- NVIDIA GeForce 210 SILENT 0dB DDR3 1GB Graphics card

Recently I've bought a local made game pad for cheap and installed it's force feedback driver. Now whenever I play any game with force feedback enabled, after the vibration, the screen turns black and windows plays the 'ta-da' sound. After I press <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>, my system plays the 'ta-da' sound again and the screen now shows.

So I tried to uninstall the driver. But when I launch the uninst.exe file in the driver folder, my antivirus AVG Home Free stops that saying that it's a trojan virus and it said Generic Trojan.D10 and the uninstaller got deleted. I've removed the files present in a file filelist.xml in the same dir manually and the registry keys and run CCleaner and it said no problems.

But even now, when I'm playing any 3D game on my system or watching a fullscreen youtube video, the screen turns black again. I suspect that there is a lose connection with my monitor and called my technician. He rechecked my cables and also formatted the entire harddisk except the windows installation folder.

How can I get around this problem? My monitor is Samsung SyncMaster 2033 if that matters.

Comment: "formatted the entire harddisk except the windows installation folder" - So is it a fresh/clean install of Windows or not?

Comment: @Karan It's not the clean install.

Comment: Does the game pad still show up as an (un)recognised device in Device Manager?

Comment: @Karan The game pad works as usual but only the force feedback driver got uninstalled.

Comment: @Karan It says `USB Composite device` in the device manager.

Comment: If the problem wasn't present before the game pad was installed you can try uninstalling its drivers/software completely and see if that helps.

Comment: @Karan My technician removed it completely. There are only NVIDIA drivers present.

Comment: Ok today I'll call my technician again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be an issue with the power supply.  If a power supply is failing when the GPU kicks in it will draw more power and that power may be unstable.  Especially since the force feedback would also draw additional power.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I'm going to call the technician since I have warranty of one year. It may be the issue probably. Thanks.